# Write values dynamically to html file stored inside assets folder

Tags: android, html, assets

I have a html file stored in my assets folder say /assets/something.html. Now I want to write  a value for it dynamically which comes from my web service. I have stored  my value into some variable and now I want this value to be written into something.html file.

Any ways to do this? When I surfed for this, I got some answers saying it is not possible, is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets are generally static, in other words you don't change them. They're there for you to use in your app only. If you need to store data persistently on the users phone (like the value you get from your web service), please take a look at the documentation for [Android Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: What I want is the html file only, I have %d in html file for which the values should be placed dynamically. Is it not possible?

Comment: Why not just have your app download the whole html file (with the value that you need in it already) from your webservice? I get the sense you might be trying to do some premature optimizations here.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reading the html file in assets folder and put them into string. Then I replaced the character which I wanted to be, with the dynamic value I got from the web service. Then I wrote this string into a new html file inside SD card and this file, now I am loading into web view